# Get evaluation value in active record reputation system gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have a system where I am using the twitter active-record-reputation-system gem (https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system/) where I have something like this:

```
class Something
  has_reputation  :rating,     source: :user,  aggregated_by: :average
end
```

And the user can vote with values from 1 to 5.

Now, I want to show the user his current rating value for that object. I searched the gem but couldn't find a way to show the user the rating that he gave, just the average value for the rating.

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to do this exact thing, I found the following in https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system/issues/30

```
this_something.evaluations('rating').where(source_type: user.class.name, source_id: user.id)
```

This basically amounts to specifying a scope to the `evaluations` method, which returns all the evaluation records.